# When using Object Mapper the format of the output is different in groovy. Why?

Tags: json, groovy, restful-architecture, object-object-mapping

Why do I get the "\" everywhere ?

Method I Use:

```
@RequestMapping(value = '/showFromMongo', method = RequestMethod.GET)
    def showFromMongoDB() {
        //println 'testit'
        def obj = repository.findByLastName("Vinodh");

        ObjectMapper myObjectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        myObjectMapper.setVisibility(PropertyAccessor.FIELD, Visibility.ANY);
        def temp = []
        obj.collect{
            temp <<  myObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(it)
            }
        temp
    }
```

OutPut I get:

```
[  
   "{\"id\":\"54fe7bbfd416859826ae53ea\",\"firstName\":\"Priya\",\"lastName\":\"Vinodh\"}",
   "{\"id\":\"54fe7be8d416f74f961678fa\",\"firstName\":\"Mrithula\",\"lastName\":\"Vinodh\"}"
]
```

What should be done to eliminate the "\".

Comment: good question, i also faced same problem while using `Newtonsoft json`!

Comment: @Vikrant, if it's a good question, upvote it.

Comment: How are you viewing the output?

Comment: As an aside, this is a *rest-like* architecture; not RESTful.

Comment: you return an array of strings.  the `\"` there get quoted.  and when using `collect` there is no need for the `temp` var.